# joomla 3.4 htaccess control of subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, joomla3.4

I need to control access to all html pages and the cgi scripts that load them at a given path within a joomla 3.4 installation. My subdirectory .htaccess file:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "EnterPassword"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

In earlier versions of joomla 3.x, the subdirectory .htaccess file pointed to the .htpasswd file and Apache requested user authentication. But with joomla 3.4 this no longer works: Apache returns a file-not-found error instead. I have not found a workable solution in stackoverflow or elsewhere.

Comment: The problem was probably a domain redirect where I should have used a redirect for the home page exclusively.

Comment: I moved the non-joomla files to a separate directory - easier to migrate and manage.